# Could not open login page for ABP Blaozr

Tags: blazor-webassembly, abp

I have created ABP IO project using the Blazor template. I can successfully run the host project and access the API interfaces from Swagger.

However the Blazor frontend does not run. I get the error message shown below:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
global.js?_v=637453952867128601:790 System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
d.printErr @ global.js?_v=637453952867128601:790
put_char @ dotnet.5.0.1.js:1
write @ dotnet.5.0.1.js:1
write @ dotnet.5.0.1.js:1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `HttpAPI.Host` project is running

Answer (score -1):

First run Http.Api.Host project. It opens a swagger web browser. Don't close it. Then set the Blazor project as startup project. Run it. It will work.